# Select multiple data fields in dropdown list

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: Data Source configuration Wizard]
[image: Database overview]

Is there a way to select multiple data fields in a dropdown list?
The reason why I need this is because `TypeKeuken` has some duplicate values. (image above)
The problem is that when I only select `TypeKeuken`, the user will see "Belgisch" 4 times. So I want the m to see `TypeZaak` and `Vegetarisch` aswell

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. If you don't want to show it to users don't write any code to show it.

Comment: Use distinct in your query

Comment: That is'nt a solution, is it? How am I going to know which "Belgisch" the user wants? (Because there are 3 options)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view that combine these columns

```
SELECT col1 + ',' + col2 + ',' + col3
FROM yourTable
```

then point your data source to the new view rather than the table.

Or you could write the select statement directly within your datasource select statement property.